# Small cactus identification

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus

I got this tiny cactus as a present for Christmas. I am sure it is a real cactus because of the areoles. Can anybody see what species it is? The diameter is about 3-4 cm (1.5 inch).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Likely to be a Gymnocalycium. It will need to be a little bigger to tell for sure. Very handsome plant, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I think you are right about that, thanks for your help!

Comment: I would guess *G. multiflorum.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnocalycium#/media/File:Gymnocalycium_multiflorum.JPG

Comment: @alephzero, indeed that looks very alike. Thanks.